Uniqueness of bubbling points in Struwe's global compactness theorem
I am reading the following paper of Struwe in which he proves the following result:
Proposition 2.1:
Let $n\geq 3$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\Omega$ be a smoothly bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}.$ Let $\left(u_{m}\right)$ be a (P.S.) sequence for $E_{\lambda}$ in $H^{1}_0(\Omega) \subset D^{1,2}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$. Then
there exist a number $k \in \mathbb{N}_{0},$ sequences $\left(R_{m}^{j}\right),\left(x_{m}^{j}\right), 1 \leq j \leq k,$ with the radii $R_{m}^{j} \rightarrow +\infty$ as $(m \rightarrow +\infty)$, a solution $u^{0} \in H^{1}_0(\Omega) \subset D^{1,2}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$
to
\begin{align}
-\Delta u&=\lambda u+u|u|^{2^{*}-2} \quad \text { in } \Omega \label{pde}\\
u&=0 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \text { on } \partial\Omega \label{boundary}
\end{align}
and non-trivial solutions $u^{j} \in D^{1,2}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right), 1 \leq j \leq k,$ to
\begin{align}\label{limiting pde}
-\Delta u=u|u|^{2^{*}-2} \quad \text { in } \mathbb{R}^{n}
\end{align}
such that a subsequence $\left(u_{m}\right)$ satisfies
$$
\left\|u_{m}-u^{0}-\sum_{j=1}^{k} u_{m}^{j}\right\|_{D^{1,2}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)} \rightarrow 0,
$$
where $u_{m}^{j}$ denotes the re-scaled function
$$
u_{m}^{j}(x)=\left(R_{m}^{j}\right)^{\frac{n-2}{2}} u^{j}\left(R_{m}^{j}\left(x-x_{m}^{j}\right)\right), 1 \leq j \leq k, m \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
Moreover, we have
$$
E_{\lambda}\left(u_{m}\right) \rightarrow E_{\lambda}\left(u^{0}\right)+\sum_{j=1}^{k} E_{0}\left(u^{j}\right),
$$
where
$$    E_{\lambda}(u) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega}(|\nabla u|^2 - \lambda|u|^2)dx -\frac{1}{2^*}\int_{\Omega}|u|^{2^*} dx.$$
Question: Are the bubbling points $x^j_m$ and the maps $u^j$ unique (up to symmetries of the PDE, of course) in this decomposition, i.e. are they independent of the subsequence?
